# Dependencies in Nuspec vs. csproj

Tags: .net-core, nuget, csproj, nuspec

I have a Dotnet Core 2.1 project which has both a nuspec and a csproj file - one major hassle is that the csproj describes dependencies like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Refit" Version="4.6.16" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Refit.HttpClientFactory" Version="4.6.16" />   
  </ItemGroup>
```

While the nuspec does this:

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Refit" version="4.6.16" />
      <dependency id="Refit.HttpClientFactory" version="4.6.16" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" version="2.1" />
    </dependencies>
```

Both are easily out of sync and keeping the same information twice is annoying.
Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I think you should mark @Alsein's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is certain to be a easy way for this, just use `dotnet pack` instead of `nuget pack` and `.csproj` files instead of `.nuspec` files.

`dotnet pack` supports 2 ways to specify the nuget package properties.

1. The legacy way: using `.nuspec` file, which would disable the 2nd way
2. The new way: [specifying them in `.csproj` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties)

`dotnet pack` supports both ways but you must add a `NuspecFile` property to reference the `.nuspec` file and there are a lot of bugs and feature missings for the legacy way, which means you can only use the new one.

`dotnet pack` executes restore and build on the project and packs it with a automatically generated .nuspec file resolving all nuget metadata properties in `.csproj` as `.nuspec` properties and all projects references as nuget package references (This is not available with manually specified `.nuspec` file), so that versioning, dependency, and package file structure things can be automatically ensured.

[My own library](https://github.com/AlseinX/Extensions) could be an example. Version and dependency things are specified for only once at where they are supposed to be and there are no longer any annoying duplicate configurations. Executing `dotnet pack` on the solution directory would generate all good `.nupkg`s on the `dist` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Do you know how to subsitute the References from the nuspec file to the csproj file? They are the only reason we use the nuspec at all:

<references>
      <group targetFramework="netcoreapp2.1">
        <reference file="service.contracts.dll" /> // dll build by another project in the solution
        <reference file="service.client.dll" /> // primary dll generated by the csproj
      </group>
    </references>

Comment: You are never recommended to reference a direct dll files. As for project references, they would be converted to nuget package references without any other specification. As for each assembly that you do not have its source project, if there is a package on nuget, use it, or you will have to pack it by yourself, and upload it to nuget.org or your own nuget server keeping it private.